# How can I get nShowCmd without WinMain?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I am using `main`, how can I retrieve `WinMain`'s `nShowCmd` parameter?

Comment: Look at [`GetStartupInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getstartupinfow)

Comment: Also note that calling `ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL)` automatically uses the `nShowCmd` value.

Comment: @jon You are probably thinking of `SW_SHOWDEFAULT`.

Comment: @IInspectable as yes, thanks!